# Convert curl for image upload to Java

Tags: java, curl

How can I convert the following CURL to Java?

```
curl "https://api.upload.io/v2/accounts/{accountId}/uploads/binary" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY" \
     -H "Content-Type: img/jpg" \
     --data-binary @file.jpg`
```

What I've tried to do (answers me 400 bad request)

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://api.upload.io/v2/accounts/{my account ID}/uploads/binary");
            post.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer {my API key}");
            post.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpg");
            post.setEntity(new FileEntity(new File("image.jpg"), ContentType.create("image/jpg")));

            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(post);
```

Comment: Your question lacks evidence of any research. Consider including what you've tried so far.

Comment: "image/jpg" may not be correct. Better use the predefined constant ContentType.IMAGE_JPEG

Comment: Can you show the response body? Because usually it tells you _why_ the request is rejected.